# azure webhook creation using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure, azure-runbook

I have created an Azure automation account and deploy a runbook using terraform. I want to publish a runbook through webhook. But in terraform, there is no such a module found for webhook.

Is there any way to create a webhook using terraform? I search on many URLs but I didn't find any useful option.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, there is no built-in terraform block to create a webhook. As a workaround, you can create it via [ARM template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.automation/automationaccounts/webhooks) or create Webhook using [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/automation/webhook/createorupdate). Read [Programmatically Creating Azure Automation Runbook Webhooks Targeting Hybrid Worker Groups](https://blog.tyang.org/2017/06/14/programmatically-creating-azure-automation-runbook-webhooks-targeting-hybrid-worker-groups/) for more details.

You can also use [azurerm_template_deployment](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/template_deployment.html) to manage the deployment of the ARM Template with terraform. Read [this blog](https://samcogan.com/deploying-arm-templates-with-terraform/) for more reference.

Comment: What value required in URI section of ARM template? In ARM template link they define "uri": "string" option. I need to generate a new URL.

Comment: I think It will automatically generate by the azure arm, it's not a required option. You could refer to "uri" in the [sample response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/automation/Webhook/CreateOrUpdate#examples).